# How to in put null is SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   Table1            Table2   
id      name    !   id  number
1       cat     !   1   10
2       dog     !   2   null
3       bat     !   3   null
4       rat     !   4   11
5       kong    !   5   null
Select *
FROM Table1 t0 left join Table2 T1 on T1.id = T2.id
id      name        number
1       cat         10
2       dog         null
3       bat         null
4       rat         11
5       kong        null
I want
id      name        number
1       cat         10
2       dog         10
3       bat         10
4       rat         11
5       kong        11
```

I need to update number in sql table

My Problem: I could not find a logic to fit in here in such a way that a where condition should work in all these three cases, so that Its should not break the existing functionality.

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what you are trying to do, please provide more clarity, and also post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE` and a subquery:

```
Select T1.ID, T1.Name, 
       COALESCE(T2.Number, (SELECT Number
                            FROM Table2 
                            WHERE Table2.Number IS NOT NULL
                             AND  Table2.ID < T1.ID
                            ORDER BY Table2.ID DESC
                            LIMIT 1)) AS Number
FROM Table1 T1 
left join Table2 T2 
    on T1.id = T2.id
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ead98/11/0)</kbd>

Comment: @utility: edited it, this approach is better. Taking the max number is arbitrary, now i'm using the last number which is not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.id, name, t2.id, 
       if(isnull(t2.number), @n, @n:=t2.number) number
  FROM Table1 t1 
    left join Table2 t2 
      on T1.id = T2.id, 
    (select @n:=0) n
```